# How do I call Pickadate javascript again after I click on "Add Item" from Cocoon gem in nested form?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5, cocoon-gem, pickadate

I have a form to create billing statements (parent) that accepts nested attributes for billing statement items (children).

Billing statement items has a due date attribute which I have wrapped a date picker, Pickadate.js on.

My nested form is made with Cocoon. Cocoon is working well.

Pickadate works upon first loading the page on the first item. However, when I add more child items, Pickadate no longer applies to the new date fields.

[See screenshot of Billing statement form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeNKE.png)

**_form.html.erb**

```
      <tbody class="billing_statement_items">
        <%= form.fields_for :billing_statement_items do |billing_statement_item| %>
          <%= render 'billing_statement_item_fields', f: billing_statement_item %>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="form-group add-item">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'Add item', form, :billing_statement_items, data: {"association-insertion-node" => "tbody.billing_statement_items", "association-insertion-method" => "append", :class => "add-items"}%>
    </div>
```

**_billing_statement_fields.html.erb**

```
<tr class="nested-fields">
  <td>
    <%= f.text_field :due_date, class: 'form-control datepicker', placeholder: 'mm/dd/yyyy', required: 'true' %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= f.select :particulars, BillingStatementItem::PARTICULARS_OPTIONS, include_blank: "Select particular", required: 'true' %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= f.text_field :amount_due, placeholder: "Amount due", required: 'true' %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove item", f%>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I feel like my problem has to do with my javascript which is only called upon loading the page:

**billing_statement.coffee**

```
$ ->
  $('.datepicker').pickadate()
```

How do I change this to call on pickadate() again when I add an item?

Answer (score 0):

With much trial and error, I found that adding a trigger upon clicking the "Add Item" button to call pickadate again somewhat works.

```
$ ->
  $('.datepicker').pickadate()

  $('a').click ->
    $('.datepicker').pickadate()
```

The only problem now is that the last (newest) rendered child item still does not have the date picker applied.

A (bad) workaround is to add one item more than necessary and delete the last item before submitting the form.

A better solution will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Cocoon has [callbacks](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#callbacks-upon-insert-and-remove-of-items) which are especially useful in a case like this. In your case you would do something like

```
$ -> 
  $('form').on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, insertedItem) {
      insertedItem.find('.datepicker').datepicker();
  });
```